# Does AWS DynamoDB consume throuput or charges for a Put Item (write) operation that failed due to a conditional expression?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I wasn't able to find a straightforward answer for this.

Consider a DynamoDB [Put Item request with a condition expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites).

Say the condition fails and DynamoDB returns an error. In other words: the Put Item request does not succeed and nothing is effectively written.

Does this request still consume write throuput capacity (or is charged, if the table is in on-demand mode)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a ConditionExpression evaluates to false during a conditional write, DynamoDB still consumes write capacity from the table:

- If the item does not currently exist in the table, DynamoDB consumes one write capacity unit.
- If the item does exist, the number of write capacity units consumed depends on the size of the item. For example, a failed conditional write of a 1 KB item would consume one write capacity unit. If the item were twice that size, the failed conditional write would consume two write capacity units.

A failed conditional write returns a `ConditionalCheckFailedException`. When this occurs, you don't receive any information in the response about the write capacity that was consumed. However, you can view the `ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits` metric for the table in Amazon CloudWatch.

This and more information can be found in the DynamoDB documentation article [Working with Items and Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Found the [section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalWrites.ReturnConsumedCapacity) that talks about it in the docs, thanks for pointing it out!